# Format version 4.8 required

Tags: java

Bonjour j ai téléchargé pokemon infinite fusion mais quand je joue au debut cela m affiche incompatible marshal fil format. Comment puis je faire ?
J ai lancer une fois la partie tout etais correct puis le lendemain cela me l as afficher

J attend de l aide .

Comment: Please read: [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Even if this were in English, it would be closed.  It isn’t about programming or programming tools.